# How to convert a "dd/mm/yyyy" string to datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, string, datetime

I tried this

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 111)
```

but got this error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

However

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '07/23/2009', 111)
```

Is OK though

How to fix the 1st one?

Comment: Have you tried using UTC format 'YYYY-MM-DD' it's a least a consistent approach and not subject to country specific settings.

Comment: Have you tried storing the date values as epoch timestamps, which are much more easier to handle than strings?

Comment: Epoch time is all but useless for dates after 2037, or before 1903 or so.  Almost any function that uses one or works with one expects it to be a signed int (32 bits, 31 either way).  You wanna use 64 bits, you risk getting your date's high bits lopped off.

Comment: @Delan Azabani, if you are using tsql, there are **much better** native date and/or time data types than a bigint epoch timestamp.

Comment: Aren't timestamps easier to work with, I mean, you could make it tomorrow just by adding 86400000.

Comment: here is tomorrow: `DECLARE @YourDate datetime; set @YourDate=GETDATE()+1` throw in all thew date functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863%28SQL.80%29.aspx and you'd be crazy to manage (debug) all of that with your own epoch code.  Try doing anything fancy, like first day of each quarter (watch out for February and leap year).

Comment: All, thanks for your input. However I can just touch the thing that already in DB, not how it was inputted

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The last argument of `CONVERT` seems to determine the format used for parsing. Consult [MSDN docs for CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

`111` - the one you are using is Japan `yy/mm/dd`.

I guess the one you are looking for is `103`, that is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

So you should try:

```
 SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 103)
```

Comment: `103` is `dd/mm/yyyy` according to [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 103)
```

this is British/French standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10), '23/07/2009', 111)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(datetime, Value, 111), 
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, Value, 103), DATEADD(year,-1,GetDate()))
```

You could add additional date formats as the `Coalesce` will go through each until it returns a successful `Try_Convert`

Comment: Very nice solution to the badly designed database problem

Answer (score 1):

You may use two ways first for the desired date format without time (00:00:00)

whereas second with time:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '23/07/2009', 103),'dd-MM-yyyy')

OUTPUT
---------------
'23/07/2009'





SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '23/07/2009', 103)

OUTPUT
---------------
'23/07/2009 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server by default uses the `mdy` date format and so the below works:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '07/23/2009', 111)
```

and this does not work:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 111)
```

I myself have been struggling to come up with a single query that can handle both date formats: `mdy` and `dmy`.

However, you should be ok with the third date format - `ymd`.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe SQL Server uses `mdy` by default. It uses your server's locale settings. Which, for you, is probably `mdy`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to a date easily by:

```
CAST(YourDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got a similar situation where the date is being held as a string in a UK format with slashes on SQL 2012 (dd/mm/yyyy).

The only thing which works for me is CONVERT(DATE, mydate, 3), this converts the date to yyyy-mm-dd correctly.

I found this blog a lot more useful than any of the answers above, none of which worked on my server, sadly I don't have the time to work out why.

https://blog.quest.com/various-ways-to-use-the-sql-convert-date-function/