# SQL SERVER how to convert a nvarchar field that contains 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

How to convert  a nvarchar field that contains 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' to datetime.
When i'm trying this conversion, it returns an error:
*"The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"*

Comment: This is one of the values I'm trying to convert: 27/01/2015 15:16:00

SELECT Convert(datetime, '27/01/2015 15:16:00')

Comment: specify a date format code... e.g. 101 I believe is standard date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a "dd/mm/yyyy" string to datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780668/how-to-convert-a-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this first:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
```

and then do the select.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(datetime, yourNVARCHARCol, 104)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.