# Converting a string to datetime within SSMS

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I'm wondering if anyone can help me?

I've got a table with two string columns that are technically dates (they are both formatted in the following way dd-mm-yyyy).

I need these to be in datetime format (specifically yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm)

I've include a small screenshot of what the data looks like.

Any help here would be brilliant. I need this for work and we're all stumped!

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using SSMS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a "dd/mm/yyyy" string to datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780668/how-to-convert-a-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: Updated my answer see the update command

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way

```
Declare @String varchar(25) = '17/02/2013'
Select convert(datetime, @String, 103)
```

Returns 2013-02-17 00:00:00.000

Ok to update your data and assuming you have a new DATETIME field to

```
Update YourTable set YourNewDateField = convert(datetime, YourDateStringField, 103)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although, it is only bringing back that one date. I need to get it to change the entire column. There's over 2million rows of data. 
Sorry, I am very new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
DECLARE @Date1 VARCHAR(50) = '31-01-2016'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @Date1, 103)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although, it is only bringing back that one date. I need to get it to change the entire column. There's over 2million rows of data. 
Sorry, I am very new to SQL.