# What I have do to with datatime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Tasks(TaskCreateDate, TaskDescription, TaskFinnishDate, TaskArchiveDate, GroupID, EmployeeID) 
VALUES ('20/01/2019', 'abc', '21/01/2019', '21/01/2019', (SELECT GroupID from TypeOfGroup WHERE GroupID='1'), (SELECT EmployeeID from Employees WHERE EmployeeID='1')),
       ('21/02/2019', 'abc', '22/02/2019', '22/02/2019', (SELECT GroupID from TypeOfGroup WHERE GroupID='2'), (SELECT EmployeeID from Employees WHERE EmployeeID='1')),
       ('22/03/2019', 'abc', '23/03/2019', '23/03/2019', (SELECT GroupID from TypeOfGroup WHERE GroupID='3'), (SELECT EmployeeID from Employees WHERE EmployeeID='1'));
```

I get an error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5):

In almost all databases (including SQL Server), you would simply use ISO/ANSI standard formats:

```
INSERT INTO Tasks(TaskCreateDate, TaskDescription, TaskFinnishDate, TaskArchiveDate, GroupID, EmployeeID)
    VALUES ('2019-01-20', 'abc', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-21',
            (SELECT GroupID from TypeOfGroup WHERE GroupID = 1), 
            (SELECT EmployeeID from Employees WHERE EmployeeID = 1)
           ),
    . . .
```

Some databases support (and Oracle requires) the ANSI-standard keyword `date` before such constants.

Note that I removed the single quotes around the "1"s for the id comparison.  This assumes that the value is numeric.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Note that in SQL Server, 2017-01-21 *almost* always means YYYY-MM-DD.  There is one international setting where it is interpreted as YYYY-DD-MM.  If you want true resiliency, remove the hyphens, `'20170121'` is *always* interpreted as YYYYMMDD in SQL Server.

Comment: Or he can convert the string to datetime. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780668/how-to-convert-a-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server