# How to convert numeric string to date in SQL

Tags: sql

How to convert
'2015030200' to 02-MAR-15

I tried this

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2015030200', 'YYYYMMDD') FROM dual;
```

But it didn't work.
Can anyone help me.

Thank you

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Refer to this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780668/how-to-convert-a-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: I guess this is related to Oracle / PLSQL if correct please add oracle tag as well, If not Oracle. Then check frank comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Sql server, convert it like this:

```
select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),20100101))
```